# Product of a Continuous and Discrete Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

> Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $Y$ be a random variable independent of $X$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> P(Y=y) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{2} & y = -1\\
> \frac{1}{2} & y = 1\\
> 0 & otherwise
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   If $ Z = XY$, show that $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Here is what I came up with:
\begin{align*}
P(Z<z) &= P(XY < z)\\
&=P(X < \frac{z}{Y})\\
&= P(X < \frac{z}{Y} \mid Y = -1)P(Y=-1) + P(X < \frac{z}{Y} \mid Y=1) P(Y=1)\\
&= \ldots\,?\\
&= P(X < z)
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to do, or whether I am even on the right track. I'd greatly appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the symmetry of the normal distribution about the Y axis.

If $Y=-1$, $Z=-X\sim -N(0,1)$. Due to the symmetry of $N(0,1)$, that means $X\sim N(0,1)$. If $Y=1$, $Z=X\sim N(0,1)$. Since the probability of either one is evenly split, it means $Z\sim N(0,1)$. If you want to do this with the conditional probability equations in your answer,
$$
\begin{align}
P(Z<z)
&=P(XY <z)\\
&=P(X<z|Y=1)P(Y=1)+P(-X<z|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)\\
&=1/2(P(X<z)+P(X>-z))
\end{align}
$$
By the symmetry of the normal distribution, 
$$P(X>-z)=1/2\pi\int_{-z}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=1/2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{z}e^{-x^2}dx=P(X<z),$$ and so
$$
P(Z<z)=P(X<z).
$$

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean... Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @oxFF You said you wanted pointers so I gave you the thing you seemed to have missed. If that was not enough, I have spelt it out explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake: you can't divide by $Y$ without knowing its sign (if it's negative, the inequality would reverse).

\begin{align*}
P(XY<z)
&= P(XY<z \mid Y=1) P(Y=1) + P(XY<z \mid Y=-1) P(Y=-1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} P(X<z) + \frac{1}{2} P(-X<z)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} P(X<z) + \frac{1}{2} P(X>-z)\\
&= P(X<z).
\end{align*}
The last step is due to symmetry: $P(X<z)=P(X>-z)$