# Product of a Discrete Uniform random variable and Continuous Circularly Symmetric Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have been trying to figure out the probability density function (pdf) of two $\textit{complex}$ random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $Y\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$. $X$ is a discrete uniform random variable $\textit{i.e.}$ $X\in [a,b]$ with $Pr(X =a ) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $Pr(X =b)=\frac{1}{2}$.

To compute the pdf of $Z=XY$, I started with following
\begin{align}
Pr(Z<z) &= Pr(XY<z)\\
&= \sum_i Pr(X_i) Pr(XY<z\vert X=X_i)\\
&= Pr(X=a)Pr(aY<z) + Pr(X=b)Pr(bY<z)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}Pr(aY<z) + \frac{1}{2}Pr(bY<z)
\end{align}

This approach is similar to this discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061955/product-of-a-continuous-and-discrete-distribution). My question is:

1. Is this a correct approach at all?
2. For real valued random variable, computing pdf of $aY$ or $bY$ is straightforward. For complex valued random variable, what should be my approach?

I understand that the query is really generalized and I wish I could I specify it better! Thanks in advance for any help.